# MySQL query for count on a date

Tags: mysql

I am trying work out a query for the following statement:

Get the total number of pets on a given day for each of the locations. Include ones that will have left on that day. Date for each booking is a start and end date.

I don't have a database of the data yet, but here is a rough idea of what the table would look like:

```
| pet | arriveDate | leaveDate  | location |
+-----+------------+------------+----------+
| 1   | 2014-11-01 | 2014-11-19 | Cat Pen  |
+-----+------------+------------+----------+
| 2   | 2014-11-02 | 2014-11-17 | Dog Pen  |
+-----+------------+------------+----------+
| 3   | 2014-11-05 | 2014-11-10 | Cat Pen  |
+-----+------------+------------+----------+
| 4   | 2014-11-06 | 2014-11-19 | Cat Pen  |
+-----+------------+------------+----------+
| 5   | 2014-11-08 | 2014-11-26 | Dog Pen  |
+-----+------------+------------+----------+
| 6   | 2014-11-14 | 2014-11-16 | Cat Pen  |
+-----+------------+------------+----------+
```

For '2014-11-08' the output would be:

```
|    date    | cat pens | dog pens |
+------------+----------+----------+
| 2014-08-11 |     3    |    2     |
```

Comment: I don't see anything you've "tried to work out", seems you're expecting someone else to. Besides, without a database how will you even know you're getting the results you expect?

Comment: Did you solve this one, OP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can start by writing the query that will just select the rows you want, before preforming any actions. You want to get pets that have arrived before or on a certain date, and have not left yet. You can filter that in your where clause, something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE arriveDate <= '2014-11-08' AND leaveDate >= '2014-11-08';
```

Then, you can use the SUM() aggregate function with a case statement to get the number for each location. It would look like this:

```
SELECT '2014-11-08' AS date, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN location = 'Cat Pen' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CatPens,
  SUM(CASE WHEN location = 'Dog Pen' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS DogPens
FROM myTable
WHERE arriveDate <= '2014-11-08' AND leaveDate >= '2014-11-08';
```

Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cc9355/2) example.

Comment: Thanks for that. It pointed me in the right direction and go it working!

Comment: @Jiggles glad I could help. What did you have to change?

Comment: It was more using joins to get other bits of data and such. Other than that it was bang on the money! :)

Comment: @Jiggles I was just looking this over, and a tiny way to cut out a few words is to use the `BETWEEN` keyword, since it is inclusive in SQL, like this: `WHERE '2014-11-08' BETWEEN arrivedate AND enddate`

Comment: Just a tiny thing I noticed, probably doesn't change performance.